# Regex- remove last word from URI

Tags: regex

I've a url `http://localhost:3001/courses/new`. I need to remove `/new` from the string.

> `http://localhost:3001/courses`

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `string.sub` function.

```
> "http://localhost:3001/courses/new".sub(/\/[^\/]*$/, "")
=> "http://localhost:3001/courses"
```

**Explanation:**

- `\/` - Matches the `/` symbol.
- `[^\/]*` - Negated character class which matches any character but not of `/`, zero or more times. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.
- `$` End of the line anchor which matches the line end.